# Elements aren't added to a list that's passed in to a recursive function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function that takes in a transform, string name, and list. It's supposed to do a recursive search through the transform to find all children whose name matches the passed in string and add it to the passed in list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        FindAllChildren(transform, "Blood", out var bloodParticles);

        print(bloodParticles.Count);
    }
    
    private void FindAllChildren(Transform parent, string name, out List<Transform> list)
    {
        list = new List<Transform>();
        
        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            if (child.name == name)
            {
                list.Add(child);
            }

            FindAllChildren(child, name, out list);
        }
    }
}
```

The console prints that the list count is zero, when it should be 3. If the list is declared and initialized outside of the function and I omit the 'out' keyword, it prints 3. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're creating a new `List<>` in each invocation of `FindAllChildren` which overwrites the last value.
- Create the `List<>` only once in the root entrypoint.
- And remove the `out` modifier:

Like so:

```
    private void Start()
    {
        List<Transform> bloodParticles = new List<Transform>();
        FindAllChildren( transform, "Blood", bloodParticles );

        print( bloodParticles.Count );
    }

    private void FindAllChildren( Transform parent, string name, List<Transform> list )
    {
        foreach( Transform child in parent )
        {
            if( child.name == name )
            {
                list.Add( child );
            }

            FindAllChildren( child, name, list );
        }
    }
```

Personally I'd use an *iterator* rather than appending to a `List<>`:

- Note that the term "Child" should only refer to the *immediate* children of a node. If you're traversing multiple levels of a tree structure then the term is "*descendant*".

```
private static IEnumerable<Transform> GetDescendants( this Transform node, Func<Transform,Boolean> predicate )
{
    if( predicate( node ) ) yield return node;

    foreach( Transform child in node )
    {
        foreach( Transform more in GetDescendants( child, predicate ) )
        {
            yield return more;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can use it like this:

```
    private void Start()
    {
        List<Transform> bloodParticles = transform
            .GetDescendants( t => t.name == "Blood" )
            .ToList();

        print( bloodParticles.Count );
    }
```

---

**Update**: Regarding `Predicate<T>` instead of `Func<T,Boolean>`:

- The `Predicate<T>` delegate predates `Func<T,Boolean>` and its use should be discouraged. It was added in .NET 2.0 in 2005.
- All the modern frameworks like Linq, Entity Framework, etc all use `Func<T,Boolean>` instead. The `Func<T>`/`Action<T>`-family were added to .NET in the .NET Framework 3.5 in 2007.
- The older `Predicate<T>` type is only used by a small number of types and methods in .NET, specifically:

  - `System.Array`

    - `System.Array.Find`, `FindAll`, `FindIndex`, etc
  - `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Exists`

    - `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Find`, `FindAll`, `FindIndex`, etc
  - That's it.

If you do want to perform those operations on a `List<T>` or `Array` then you can use the Linq extension methods (which use `Func<T,Boolean>` instead of `Predicate<T>`) and they'll perform *with the same performance* as the original methods, albeit with the *possible exception* of expressions using `Skip` - and the backwards-iterating methods `FindLast`, `FindLastIndex`, etc which can be reimplemented easily enough but are beyond the scope of this answer - and `List<T>.RemoveAll` which is beyond the scope of Linq as Linq is only concerned with read-only queries, not mutating data.

```
Classic Predicate<T> methods                Linq Func<T,Boolean> alternative
------------------------------------------------------------------------
List<T>.Exists( f )                         .Any( f )
List<T>.Find( f )                           .FirstOrDefault( f )
List<T>.FindAll( f )                        .Where( f ).ToList()
List<T>.FindIndex( f )                      .Select( ( e, idx ) => ( e, idx ) ).FirstOrDefault( f )?.idx
List<T>.FindIndex( startIndex, f )          .Skip( startIndex ).Select( ( e, idx ) => ( e, idx ) ).FirstOrDefault( f )?.idx
List<T>.FindIndex( startIndex, count, f )   .Skip( startIndex ).Take( count ).Select( ( e, idx ) => ( e, idx ) ).FirstOrDefault( f )?.idx
List<T>.TrueForAll( f )                     .All( f )
```

While C# does not allow for *structural equivalence* of nominative delegate types (which is understandable given C# and .NET is couched in a nominative type system with hardly any structural type support), C# *does* allow for implicit conversion from a method-reference (be it a class member method, `delegate() {}`-style anonymous method, `() =>` -style lambda method, or inline function) to any compatible delegate type. Though this won't help you much here.

...so if you *really* need compatibility with a prior `Predicate<T>` reference, just add an extension method to invoke it:

```
private static IEnumerable<Transform> GetDescendants( this Transform node, Predicate<Transform> legacyPredicate )
{
    if( legacyPredicate is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(legacyPredicate));

    return GetDescendants( node: node, predicate: t => legacyPredicate( t ) );
}
```

Comment: What about initializing the list inside of FindAllChildren only if it hasn't been already initialized?

Comment: @SeanCarey You can't do that with `out` parameters, it would need to be `ref` - but then you'll need to check it every time which is needlessly complicated when you can just set it once at the start. If you have multiple entrypoints then you can create a `public` wrapper function that initializes it and then make the real implementation `private`.

Comment: Unity's ```Transform``` doesn't maintain its child collection in an IEnumerable, unfortunately (Oh how I wish it did, but I guess it's a unmanaged/optimisation thing), and can only be accessed with a getter function that takes an index parameter.  The answer about creating a new ```List<>``` every time is obviously still true.

Comment: Great. What about replacing Func with Predicate? That way I don't need to explicitly declare the return type as bool.

Comment: @SeanCarey I've updated my answer to discuss `Predicate<T>`. You shouldn't be using `Predicate<T>` anymore though as `Func<T,Boolean>` completely replaces it.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for taking the time to explain all of that to me. I'm going to use Func instead of Predicate.